# How to Group the Pandas Dataframe & Show them HTML Tables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

***Hi, how to get an HTML Table like the one on the right which is 'Grouped Table' by Grouping from the Pandas DataFrame on the left?***

---

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.